# MVC Ajax Beginform doesn't perform client model validation

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, ajaxform

I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

Trying to create a simple Ajax Form in MVC with clientside validation. 
Here's what I've done so far.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAsync", "Page", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" , OnComplete= "", OnSuccess= "P3Functions.onCreateSuccess()" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partial/_createPageCore.cshtml", Model)
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" onclick="P3Functions.closeCreate()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It's a form that loads a partial view with the form content. (I've also tried to insert the code directly into the page. No difference)

This form gets loaded into a div using Ajax.ActionLink.

```
    <div class="pageItem_control">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Page", "PartialCreate", new { controller = "Page" },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "createFormDivId",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "GET"
            },
            new { @class = "btn btn-default", @onclick = "P3Functions.displayCreate()" })
    </div>
```

Other configurations:

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Bundle config

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomScript")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

PageModel.cs

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Title is required")]
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }
```

_createPageCore.cshtml

```
<h4>Create New Page</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment it directly goes to the server without any client side validation. However on serverside ModelState is not valid.

Any thoughts or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue:

Chuck in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formId");
</script>
```

Where you're loading form content. This parses the newly added DOM fields.

Comment: Not very efficient since you parsing the DOM twice. The first line should be  `$('#formId').data('validator', null);` to remove the validator

Comment: That was a copy/paste typo :). I removed the validator using $(form).removeData("validator");